# Memory leak when uploading files with PowerShell 5 Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: file-upload, memory-leaks, powershell-5.0

I've created a backup script that uploads a series a big files through WebDAV over HTTPS. The code that performs the upload is the following:

```bsh
 Invoke-WebRequest `
   -Uri "$url/$name" `
   -Credential $cred `
   -Method Put `
   -ContentType 'application/octet-stream' `
   -InFile $File
```

Every file weights ~200MB, and after some uploads, it just fails, while the process uses a ton of memory, approximately the total weight of the uploaded files. This looks like a memory leak.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? Another option is to resort to `curl`, but I'd prefer to keep things self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

The thing was solved in PowerShell 7 apparently, it doesn't reproduce the issue anymore. So the current workaround is to install the v7 preview.